Finitely generated submodules of a direct product
Let $M$ be a left module on a certain ring $R$ with $1$, and let $M^A$ be the direct product of the module $M$ by an arbitrary index set $A$. Assume $N$ to be a finitely generated (for instance,  a cyclic) submodule of $M^A$. My question is: what is the general form of the elements of $N$? Apparently, if $N$ is such a, say,  cyclic submodule generated by $s$, then $s$ would be a tuple by the index set $A$ whose components belong to $M$. Is there  any concrete characterization of the elements of $N$?

Sure, just use the definition of the generated submodule? I doubt that this is really what you are asking ... Please provide more context.
